# Checking if the current date is already due

Tags: java, sql, date

So this if the code that i've come up. It gives me the correct due date that is in the database and the correct current date. I wanted to work on how to check if the current date is already due.

```
String search = "SELECT * FROM tbltransaction"; 
PreparedStatement ps2 = con.prepareStatement(search);

ResultSet rs2;
rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();
try{
   if(rs2.next()){
   SimpleDateFormat formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
   String dateOfDue = (String)(formattedDate.format(rs2.getDate("dateOfReturn").getTime()));
   Date dateToday = new Date();
   }
}catch(Exception e){
   System.err.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: This link may help you https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java/

Comment: @SophiaDeLeon I have posted it as an answer.Accept the answer if it works.

Comment: This Question uses troublesome old classes that are now supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it via java.util.Date or you can use Apache common DateUtils. The following link may helpful for you.
[Compare Dates](http://mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java)

Let us know for any challenges.

Comment: This Answer is outmoded with the arrival of the java.time classes in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The Question and other Answers use troublesome old classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes built into Java 8 and later.

The `LocalDate` class is used for date-only values without time-of-day and without time zone.

Retrieve from database using `getObject` rather than `getDate` with a driver compliant with JDBC 4.2 or later.

```
LocalDate ld = rs2.getObject( "dateOfReturn" , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

Considering **time zone is crucial** to determining the current date. For any given moment, the date varies around the world by zone. A new day dawns earlier in `Pacific/Auckland` than in `America/Montreal`, for example.

```
ZoneId z = `Asia/Kolkata` ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Compare using `isEqual`, `isBefore`, and `isAfter` methods.

```
Boolean expired = ld.isBefore( today ) ;
```

This topic has been addressed many time already. So search Stack Overflow to learn more.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the current-date and due-date into timestamp.Then compare this two timestamp by using if-else statement.Then you will get to know if the current-date is due-date or not.